# How to use HBase with Spark 2?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-2.0

I'm updating the versions from a project (in Scala) and I'm having some problems with Hbase. The version I updated to are:

- scala-library  -> 2.11.12
- scalatest_2.11 -> 3.0.8
- spark-streaming_2.11 -> 2.4.3
- spark-sql_2.11 -> 2.4.3
- spark-hive_2.11 -> 2.4.3

Hereupon, I can't get any hbase-spark that works, having always the same compiling error:

> Error: Symbol 'type org.apache.spark.Logging' is missing from the
>   classpath. This symbol is required by 'class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext'. Make sure that type
>   Logging is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies
>   with `-Ylog-classpath`.
>
> A full rebuild may help if 'HBaseContext.class' was compiled against
>   an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.
>
> ```
> val hBaseContext = new HBaseContext(sc, hBaseConf)
> ```

Comment: This suggests that you're using a version of `hbase-spark` that's been compiled for Spark 1.x.

Comment: Are you aware of any compatible version for Spark 2.x?

Comment: No sorry I've never used this connector.

Comment: What is the version of HBase are you using?

Comment: I'm moving from 1.2.0 (Cloudera 5.14.0) to 1.4.9 (AWS EMR). In 1.2.0 I was using [cloudera spark to hbase connector](https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/hbase/hbase-spark/1.2.0-cdh5.14.0/) (1.2.0-cdh5.14.0)